# Checking out old revision from Xcode Organiser

Tags: xcode, svn, repository, xcode-organizer

I am using Xcode v4.6.3 and my repository server type is subversion. I couldn't find a way to checkout older revisions. Is there a way to do it? If not what tool should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way remains the command-line interface with svn:

```
svn checkout -r xxx  PATH
```

Or you can [use another GUI in complement of XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/899/6309).